Is there a global way to know if a user is in an input or other contenteditable element?
I'm trying to implement Gmail-style (well, vim-style) j/k keyboard shortcuts to move up and down through items in a list. I've done it by adding a keydown handler directly to the document that listens for j and k presses.
However, certain elements on the page include inputs or other contenteditable elements that the user needs to be able to type in - and if they type j or k in these inputs there's a problem: it also gets captured by the keydown handler on the document.
Is there a way to tell in the keydown handler if the user is currently typing into a input or other contenteditable element, so it knows to do nothing?
Or is there a better approach to what I'm trying to do?
Thanks!
Extra context that might be useful: this is in a React app, and the component that includes the input and the list component that handles the keyboard shortcuts are different, and ideally wouldn't be coupled together (i.e. the input element should not need to know about the container element that handles the keyboard shortcuts).
Stuff I've tried:
I've tried adding a keydown handler to the input element with a stopPropagation call, but a) it didn't work, and b) it would be a bit annoying to have to do this with every single input that gets added to the page.
I tried getting document.activeElement in the keydown handler to see if there were any properties/methods on it I could use, but can't see anything obviously helpful.

What about listening to the input event on window?

If you are trying to move up and down through items in a list, why not just attach the event handler to the list element?

@RayWallace the list items themselves can contain content editable elements. (It’s also quite helpful behaviour that pressing j or k moves to the next element regardless of whether the list is currently focused or not, but I could live without that)

I'd just do something like this to see if the event's target or any of its parents smell editable (which could be customized e.g. with dataset too).


function shouldIgnoreInputEvent(event) {
  let target = event.target;
  while (target && target !== document.body) {
    if (target.tagName === "TEXTAREA") return true;
    if (target.tagName === "INPUT") return true;
    if (target.contentEditable) return true;
    target = target.parentNode;
  }
  return false;
}

document.body.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
  const log = document.getElementById("log");
  if (shouldIgnoreInputEvent(event)) {
    log.value += "Ignoring: " + event.key + "\n";
  } else {
    log.value += "Handling: " + event.key + "\n";

  }
});
<input value="hello">
<textarea>hello</textarea>
<div contenteditable>hello</div>
<hr />
<textarea id=log readonly rows=10></textarea>




Thanks! I’ve done exactly this. Are there any performance concerns you can think of with this approach, traversing the tree of nodes on every key press?

Probably not. If you want to be clever about it (and don't expect your nodes to move about in the tree), have the traversal set e.g. a dataset attribute on the node to skip the traversal next time.
